# Dont create nested form if select exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Currently I'm developing a pharmacy system, so I want to create a prescription with specific professional, patient and medication. For doing that, I'm using some gems like simple_form, chosen_rails and cocoon. But when I create a new prescription without filling the professional's fields but selecting a professional I get the following error:

```
> Started POST "/prescriptions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-05 21:08:42 -0300
Processing by PrescriptionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "prescription"=>{"professional_id"=>"1", "professional_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "dni"=>"", "enrollment"=>"", "sector_id"=>"", "sector_attributes"=>{"sector_name"=>"", "description"=>"", "complexity_level"=>""}}, "patient_id"=>"1", "patient_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "dni"=>"", "patient_type_id"=>""}, "quantity_medications_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"medication_id"=>"", "quantity"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "quantity_supplies_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"supply_id"=>"", "quantity"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "observation"=>"", "date_received"=>"01/05/2018 9:08 PM"}, "commit"=>"Cargar y dispensar"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Patient Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "patients".* FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Professional Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "professionals".* FROM "professionals" WHERE "professionals"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  PrescriptionStatus Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "prescription_statuses".* FROM "prescription_statuses" WHERE "prescription_statuses"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Dispensada"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  PatientType Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "patient_types".* FROM "patient_types" WHERE "patient_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
> 
> 
>ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - Validation failed: Professional first name can't be blank, Professional last name can't be blank, Professional dni can't be blank, Professional sector must exist:
  app/controllers/prescriptions_controller.rb:82:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/prescriptions_controller.rb:81:in `create'
```

---

**My prescription controller is:**

```
class PrescriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_prescription, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def new
    @prescription = Prescription.new
    @professionals = Professional.all
    @medications = Medication.all
    @supplies = Supply.all
    @patients = Patient.all
    @sectors = Sector.all
    @patient_types = PatientType.all
    @prescription.build_professional
    @prescription.professional.build_sector
    @prescription.build_patient
    @prescription.quantity_medications.build
    @prescription.quantity_supplies.build
  end

  def create
    @prescription = Prescription.new(prescription_params)
    if dispensing?
      @prescription.prescription_status = PrescriptionStatus.find_by_name("Dispensada")
      @prescription.date_dispensed = DateTime.now
    end
    @prescription.prescription_status = PrescriptionStatus.find_by_name("Pendiente") if loading?

    date_r = prescription_params[:date_received]
    @prescription.date_received = DateTime.strptime(date_r, '%d/%M/%Y %H:%M %p')

    respond_to do |format|
      if @prescription.save!
        flash.now[:success] = "La prescripción de "+@prescription.professional.full_name+" se ha creado correctamente."
        format.js
      else
        flash.now[:error] = "La prescripción no se ha podido crear."
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def prescription_params
      params.require(:prescription).permit(
  :observation, :date_received, 
  :professional_id, :patient_id, :prescription_status_id,                                             
  quantity_medications_attributes: [:id, :medication_id, :quantity, 
  :_destroy],
  quantity_supplies_attributes: [:id, :supply_id, :quantity, :_destroy],
  patient_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :dni, :patient_type_id],
  professional_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :dni, :enrollment, :sector_id,
  sector_attributes: [:id, :sector_name, :description, :complexity_level]                        ])
  end
end
```

**My models are:**

```
class Prescription < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :patient
  validates_presence_of :prescription_status
  validates_presence_of :professional

  belongs_to :professional
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :prescription_status

  has_many :quantity_medications, :as => :quantifiable, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :quantifiable
  has_many :medications, :through => :quantity_medications
  has_many :quantity_supplies, :as => :quantifiable, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :quantifiable
  has_many :supplies, :through => :quantity_supplies


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantity_medications,
          :reject_if => :all_blank,
          :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantity_supplies,
          :reject_if => :all_blank,
          :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :medications
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patient,
          :reject_if => :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :professional,
          :reject_if => :all_blank
  def dispensed?
    self.prescription_status.is_dispense?
  end
end

class Professional < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :dni, presence: true

  has_many :prescriptions
  belongs_to :sector

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sector,
    :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Sector < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :sector_name, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :complexity_level, presence: true  

  has_many :professionals
end
```

**My tables are:**

```
  create_table "prescriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "observation"
    t.datetime "date_received"
    t.datetime "date_dispensed"
    t.integer "prescription_status_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "professional_id"
    t.bigint "patient_id"
    t.index ["patient_id"], name: "index_prescriptions_on_patient_id"
    t.index ["professional_id"], name: "index_prescriptions_on_professional_id"
  end

  create_table "professionals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.integer "dni"
    t.string "enrollment"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "sector_id"
    t.index ["sector_id"], name: "index_professionals_on_sector_id"
  end

  create_table "sectors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "sector_name"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "complexity_level"
    t.string "applicant"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**And finally, my form is:**

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @prescription, remote: true, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :professional_id,
                    label: 'Doctor',
                    label_method: :full_name,
                    value_method: :id,
                    collection: @professionals,
                    include_blank: false,
                    input_html: { class: 'chosen-select', id: 'professional_id' },
                    prompt: 'Seleccione un doctor o cree uno'
  %><br><br>
  <%= f.hint 'No seleccione ningún doctor para crear uno nuevo.', id: 'professional-hint', style: "display: none" %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :professional, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |form_professional| %>
    <%= render "professional_fields", :f => form_professional %>
  <% end %><br>

  <%= f.input :patient_id,
                    label: 'Paciente',
                    label_method: :full_info,
                    value_method: :id,
                    collection: @patients,
                    include_blank: false,
                    input_html: { class: 'chosen-select', id: 'patient_id' },
                    prompt: 'Seleccione un paciente o cree uno'
  %><br><br>
  <%= f.hint 'No seleccione ningún paciente para crear uno nuevo.', id: 'patientHint', style: "display: none" %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :patient, html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |form_patient| %>
    <%= render "patient_fields", :f => form_patient %>
  <% end %><br>

  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
      <label>Medicación</label>
      <div id="quantity-medications">
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :quantity_medications, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |form_quantity| %>
            <%= render "quantity_medication_fields", :f => form_quantity %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="links">
            <%= link_to_add_association f, :quantity_medications, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' do %>
                <%= content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus') %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
      <label>Suministro</label>
      <div id="quantity-supplies">
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :quantity_supplies, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |form_quantity| %>
            <%= render "quantity_supply_fields", :f => form_quantity %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="links">
            <%= link_to_add_association f, :quantity_supplies, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' do %>
                <%= content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus') %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
      <%= f.input :observation, label: 'Observaciones', as: :text,
          :input_html => { :cols => 46  , :rows => 2 } %>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
      <%= f.input :date_received, label: 'Fecha recibida',
                                  as: :string,
                                  :placeholder => "Seleccionar fecha",
                                  input_html: {class: "form-control", required: true,
                                  value: "#{@prescription.date_received.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M") unless @prescription.new_record?}"},
                                  html5: false
                                  %><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_professional_fields.html.erb**

```
<div id='form-professional'>
  <%= f.input :first_name, placeholder: 'Nombre', required: true, label: false %>
  <%= f.input :last_name, placeholder: 'Apellido', required: true, label: false %>
  <%= f.input :dni, placeholder: 'DNI', required: true, label: false, input_html: { min: '10000', max:'99999999' } %>
  <%= f.input :enrollment, placeholder: 'Matrícula', label: false, input_html: { min: '1000', max:'9999' } %>
  <%= f.input :sector_id,
                    label: false,
                    label_method: :sector_name,
                    value_method: :id,
                    collection: @sectors,
                    include_blank: false,
                    input_html: { class: 'chosen-select', id: 'sector_id', onchange: "" },
                    prompt: 'Seleccione un sector o cree uno nuevo'
  %>
  <br><br>
  <%= f.hint 'No seleccione ningun sector para crear uno nuevo', id: 'sector-hint', style: "display: none" %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :sector, html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |fs| %>
    <div id='form-sector'>
      <label>Nuevo sector</label>
      <%= fs.input :sector_name, placeholder: 'Nombre sector', required: true, label: false %>
      <%= fs.input :description, as: :string, placeholder: 'Descripción', required: true, label: false %>
      <%= fs.input :complexity_level, label: false, required: true, input_html: { min: '0', max:'10' } %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I want to create a new prescription only selecting the professional in the chosen select avoiding create a new professional. I have another model called Medication with nested forms like MedicationBrand and sub nested form called Laboratory and what I want to do worked perfectly.

What am I doing wrong in this Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `:reject_if => :all_blank` set, but because of the sub-nesting in your professional attributes, that isn't working as you might expect. The `:all_blank` option is explained in the docs at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html:

```
REJECT_ALL_BLANK_PROC   =   proc { |attributes| attributes.all? { |key, value| key == "_destroy" || value.blank? } }
```

Your professional attributes come in to the controller as follows:

```
"professional_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "dni"=>"", "enrollment"=>"", "sector_id"=>"", "sector_attributes"=>{"sector_name"=>"", "description"=>"", "complexity_level"=>""}}
```

The `sector_attributes` value isn't blank, as it's a sub-nested hash that just happens to have all blank values itself. As such, the `professional_attributes` aren't rejected, and it tries to process them.

For your `:reject_if`, you want to use your own custom proc instead to check the values for `professional_attributes`, and to also deal with any sub-hashes as blank as well.

This should work for your input attributes:

```
:reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes.all? { |key, value| key == "_destroy" || value.blank? || (value.is_a?(Hash) && value.values.all?(&:blank?)) } }
```

If you wanted to have any further sub-nesting of hashes, you'd need to consider a recursive function, although I'd suggest that at that point you might need to reconsider your design as to why you had so many levels of nesting in a single form and whether it was truly necessary.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much!!! i put the :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes.all? { |key, value| key == "_destroy" || value.blank? || (value.is_a?(Hash) && value.values.all?(&:blank?)) } } to the professionals and works! You have totally reason on reconsider of the nesting levels.